# Override html template per NODE type in Drupal 7?

Tags: templates, drupal-7

I know how to override the standard html.tpl.php file. The problem is, I need to apply a certain HTML template for node type one, and another html.tpl.php for node type two. Is there an easy way to just include a template that would work like this? I was hoping if my node has the type "mynode", that it would be as simple as overriding:

```
html--mynode.tpl.php
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to add some additional code, in `YOURTHEME_preprocess_html`, according to the following thread in the Drupal forums:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1041768.

Hope that helps,